net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and Uncaught Error when using Axios with TanStack-Query useMutation (asyncMutation)
On my app i tried to implement a simple login, which is working fine if my server is running. But when my backend is offline, i try to catch the error and show it to the user. But i still get unwanted errors in my console, even if i wrapped everything with try/catch and handle those errors. In this case i do not understand why i can't catch the error in my apiLoginMutation, but get a uncaught error in my console.
My used setup

Vite (with TypeScript)
React
TanStack Query
TanStack Router
Axios
React Hook Form

My console output
That's how i set everything up.
AuthPage Component
const AuthPage = () => {

    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm<LoginFormSchemaType>({
        resolver: zodResolver(LoginFormSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            email: "",
            password: "",
        },
    });

    const { mutateAsync: apiLoginMutation } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: APILogin,
        onSuccess: () => {
            //Handle the redirect
        },
        onError: (error: AxiosError) => {
            console.log("Error in onError: " + error.message);
        },
    });

    const onSubmit = async (data: LoginFormSchemaType) => {
        try {
            apiLoginMutation(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error on apiLoginMutation call: " + error); //This never gets called! 
        }
    };

    return ( //JSX Stuff as Form)
};

http.ts
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:8000/api";

export type LoginData = {
    email: string;
    password: string;
};

export async function APILogin(formData: LoginData) {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(
            `${API_URL}/login`,
            { email: formData.email, password: formData.password },
            { withCredentials: true }
        );
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${data.token}`;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}

As said above, i've tried to wrap everything in try/catches, but never got to the point, that no error is shown to my console. Also tried to build my app (with vite) and run as preview. All errors are still visible, because i've read about some DEVMODE Parts to show everytime, but they appeared even on the production build, so i can't confirm those theories (<--- relates mostly to the POST http://localhost:8000/api/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in console)

I've changed my http.ts to work with the errors, but the problem is with this i can't use my onError call in the useMutation.  (Console output without any new throw ). No throw calls onSuccsess.
If i throw a new Error to get use of my onError everything gets back to "normal broken" again. (Console output with throw new Error("XYZ"))
But anyways the error with POST .... net::ERROR_CONNECTION_ERROR is visible all time and i don't know where to catch it.
My new http.ts on Pastebin

I don't think you can ever prevent the error in the console, because browsers tend to log failed request by default. fetch('https://stackoverflow.com').catch(console.log) will log an error if you are on any other site because of CORS even though it should be caught. That's just how the dev tools work.

@JakubKotrs thanks for the information, never thought about this... But seems logical to me.
So the question is still about my uncaught error in my AuthPage Component (because i need to throw it to handle my errors in the onError from react-query).
Console
Part that fails <--- Full code is above.
Why dosen't my try/catch work in that place so i will get the uncaught error?

        try {
            apiLoginMutation(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error on apiLoginMutation call: " + error); //This never gets called! 
        }

This part is not catching any errors because apiLoginMutation is async, you need to await it.
        try {
            await apiLoginMutation(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error on apiLoginMutation call: " + error); //This never gets called! 
        }

This should make a difference.

Ohhh... wow. Didn't noticed it...
But can i get rid of this try/catch so the error handling is in onError? Because for me it looks like redundancy to implement the same error handling two times. Even if i used functions to handle those. Overall its the same "call" or isn't it?

Yes, you can keep it in one place until you find a good reason to have it in two places.

But if try/catch is removed it is uncaught again. Is the "correct" way to try { await apiLoginMutation(data); } catch (_error) { //Do nothing here, because onError is in charge } Or is there another better solution?

You have catch (err) { throw err; } in APILogin. By "keep it in one place" I thought you would instead handle the error there, inside APILogin, to now re-throw it.

Unfortunately i need to throw the error otherwise onSuccess from Tanstack-Query will get triggered all the time, this is why i thought about to handle the error finally in my onError from Tanstack aswell. This is why i asked if i can avoid try/catch on the apiLoginMuation(data) with _error. So the real handling get done in onError, but this solution didn't seem right/correct to me :/
